# Activator.CreateInstance throws Exception "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: c#, system.reflection, createinstance

I've copied code for an assembly that is used in a solution to create a similar assembly. The GUTS was different, but the shell stayed the same.

These assemblies are used in a project at a client that are add-on's and not part of our core code. Now that I'm finished the assembly does not want to load like it is supposed to.

The code that loads the assembly is

```
var assemblyName = ((XmlElement)xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AssemblyName")[0]).InnerText;
var qualifiedClass = ((XmlElement)xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("QualifiedClass")[0]).InnerText;

IExternalAddOn addOn = (IExternalAddOn)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, qualifiedClass).Unwrap();
var properties = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
properties[typeof(DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonControl)] = mainForm.ribbon;
var form = addOn.ShowForm(properties);
if (form != null)
{
form.MdiParent = mainForm;
form.Text = pListRow.NAME;
form.Show();
```

I get the exception on the CreateInstance part.

The interesting thing is that when I use

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName); // this is test code
Type at = ass.GetType(qualifiedClass);
IExternalAddOn addOn = (IExternalAddOn)Activator.CreateInstance(at);
```

to load the assembly and get the type, and CreateInstance it works.

Why do you need the Unwrap? Is there a difference in the two different ways of loading? And WHY does the first one not work?

Thanks

J

Comment: Unwrap is called because [the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an [ObjectHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than a normal reference to the object. Unfortunately, I don't really understand why the method was designed to return an `ObjectHandle`. I'm guessing it's because passing a string name doesn't by itself load the type metadata into memory, so you have the option of doing so when you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as `Assembly.LoadFrom` works, I guess you are passing a file name as an `assemblyName` parameter, which is wrong in case of `Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, qualifiedClass)`.

According to [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) documentation:

> assemblyName can be either of the following:
>
> - The simple name of an assembly, without its path or file extension. For example, you would specify TypeExtensions for an assembly whose path and name are .\bin\TypeExtensions.dll.
> - The full name of a signed assembly, which consists of its simple name, version, culture, and public key token; for example, "TypeExtensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=181869f2f7435b51".

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. What does `UnWrap` do exactly then if it works without it when I use the `Type`, or does it already unwrap because I `CreateInstance` from the `Type`